# Why Ctrl+C randomly goes to another piece of the code?

Tags: eclipse, copy, copy-paste

My first question here.

As I'm writing code normaly, sometimes I need to copy. And like every 50-100 Ctrl+C copys, the mouse pointer goes to another part of the code and it doesn't copy what was selected (I mainly use eclipse IDE, but I believe this happened in other editors). It's like I was pressing Ctrl+LMB.
This kinda happens randomly and I can't seem to replicate it. I believe I'm misclicking a key but I never do realize what I just did.

This can really piss me off and I can't find anything online related.

Is it just me? Does anyone have an ideia what could be happening?

Comment: Try a different keyboard.  If your keyboard has (somehow) become defective, it might be sending the wrong 'signals' to the computer

Comment: It cannot be the keyboard, I got a new keyboard this weak and I have had this headache for more than 2 years now... This happens on a desktop, no mousepad neither trackpoint. Sry, already removed the java tag!

Comment: It may be related to the OS perhaps?

Comment: It could be a keyboard driver then.  In either case, does this only happen with the eclipse IDE or does it happen every time (even in other editors or browsers)?  The question has very little details so it's impossible to troubleshoot.  Please read our [ask] page

Comment: The thing is that is a completely different keyboard, they use different drivers right? It happens often, like every 50-100 Ctrl+C's. I mainly use Eclipse, but it may also happened in another editors, I think...